# Loop int counter suddently becomes a string

Tags: python, function, while-loop, parameters

So, i am making an hangman type game, and i tried to organize the code better inside of functions creating a char_replace functions where if the letter by the user is in the word, it replace the _  with the corresponding letter. Before this there was no problem but then if i run the code the following error appear:

```
**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**
```

refering to the start of the loop

```
File "C:\Users\Username\PycharmProjects\Hangman-1\main.py", line 17, in main
    while g < len(r) * 2:
```

that confuse me, how did the counter suddently became a variable, have i done something wrong? i tried putting into parameters, but it just doesn't make any sense, and it doesn't work, i also tried converting it to an int but this error appears:

`**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'**`

```
    def start():
        r = random.choice(['Ciao', 'Parrucchiere', 'Dio', 'Baduini', 'Gisualdo', 'Mario', 'Manue', 
        'Salini', 'Giacomo'])
    
        occulta = []
        g = 0
        for i in r:
            occulta.append("_")
    
        print("The word has " + str(len(r)) + " letters!")
        main(g, r, occulta)
    
    def main(g, r, occulta):
        while g < len(r) * 2:
    
            x = input(">")
    
    
            if x not in r:
                g += 1
    
            if x == r:
                print("That's right!")
                start()
    
            if len(x) > 1:
                print("Insert only a letter!")
                main(g, r, occulta)
    
            if x.upper() == r[0]:
                occulta[0] = x.upper()
                for i in occulta:
                    print(i, end="")
                print("")
    
            if x in r:
                char_repl(x, r, occulta , g)
    
    
        print("You failed too many times, try again")
        start()
    
    def char_repl(x, r, occulta):
        
    
        az = [i for i in range(len(r)) if r.startswith(x, i)]  # Find index of letters
    
        for i in az:
            occulta[r.index(x, i)] = x  # replace empty space with letters
        for i in occulta:
            print(i, end="")
        print("")
    
    
        if occulta.count("_") == 0:  # If he guessed all the letters, he won
            print("Hai indovinato!")
            start()
    
        main(x, r, occulta)
```

Comment: It looks like you are supposed to have: `def char_repl(x, r, occulta, g):` and then at the last line: `main(g, r, occulta)`. Where you have `main(x, r, occulta)` the `x` is a character from one of the random words.

Comment: so, trying to understand completely parameters, passing x in main() is useless because the value will inevitably change, and i need to pass g because if i then use main function again it won't know what g is, is that the reason why is it considered a string? i don't understand that.

Comment: It's because you do `if x in r: char_repl(x, r, occulta, g)`, and x is a string, from `x = input(">")` and then, at the end of `char_repl`, you call `main` with `x` in the place of `g`, which is supposed to be an `int`, but not.

Comment: I've had a rethink, maybe you should delete the last line: `main(x, r, occulta)`. Also there is too much recursion in the code already.

Comment: I don't think you need to call `main` at all, because at the end, `char_repl` just exits back into `main`. Also, when you call `char_repl`, you give it another parameter that's not defined in the definition of `char_repl`